# jQuery - Find Label By The Inner Text

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I was wondering if it was possible to find a label (or any element, really) by it's inner text. For example:

```
<label for="myCheckbox">SuperSweetCheckbox</label>
```

And I want to find it by the text `SuperSweetCheckbox`.

I know this seems kind of counter-intuitive, but due to the nature of the app I'm working on it seems to be necessary. I realize that I can iterate through each of the labels but I'd prefer to avoid that option if at all possible.

If anyone could provide some assistance, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

use the selector **[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**

```
 var element = $("label:contains('SuperSweetCheckbox')");
```

The matching text **can appear directly** within the selected element, in any of that **element's descendants, or a combination thereof**. As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of `:contains()` can be written as bare words or surrounded by quotation marks. The text must have matching case to be selected.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe

```
$('label[value|="SuperSweetCheckbox"]')
```

according to:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

or

```
$("label:contains('SuperSweet')")
```

according to

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: The first one won't work. The `label` element has no attribute `value`.

Comment: @Felix but it's the value of the element according to DOM.

Comment: It is not. If I inspect the element, then there is no `value` attribute. But convince yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/xd8Pf/ `value` is a well defined attribute. The inner text of elements is *not* the value of those elements.

Answer (score 3):

This builds on Caspar's answer, but was too big for comments.

I thought it could be useful for others.

I used Caspar's solution but found that an empty string `""` is considered to exist in any string, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18399216/1063287.

In my situation `SuperSweetCheckbox` is a dynamic value and sometimes an empty string, in which case I don't want any matching logic to occur.

Creating a pseudo function using `match()` seems to work, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462522/1063287.

You can also use `filter()`, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15364327/1063287).

Below is an example of the three variants - `:contains()`, `filter()` and a custom function:

**jsFiddle**

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/06n9o09h/)

**jQuery**

```
var myString = "Test";

//var myString = "";

// 01.  :contains() - matches empty string as well
$("ul li > label:contains(" + myString + ")").closest("li").addClass("matched").siblings("li").addClass("notmatched");

// 02.  filter()
$("ul li > label").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === myString;
}).closest("li").addClass("matched").siblings("li").addClass("notmatched");

// 03.  custom function
$.expr[':'].textEquals = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().match("^" + arg + "$");
    };
});

$("ul li > label:textEquals(" + myString + ")").closest("li").addClass("matched").siblings("li").addClass("notmatched");
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>
<label>Test</label>
</li>
<li>Oh Nu</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.matched {
background: yellow
}

.notmatched {
background: aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `:contains()` selector is what you are looking for. Check samples here > http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Unfortunately this selector chooses text that can be a substring of the actual value you are looking for. Example value you are looking for: test, Value in label: this is a test. This means that it will choose values that you dont need. I havent found a way around it unfortunately.

Answer (score -3):

All the Above specified is very exclusive, but try out this too, if its not working let me know.

```
VAR $YesitHas=$("lable").innerText("SuperSweetCheckBox");
```