# Why does contains() method find empty string in non-empty string in Java

Tags: java, string

This is a weird behavior I found with Java's `String.indexOf()` and `String.contains()` methods. If I have a *non-empty* string says `blablabla` and I try to look for an empty string inside it, it always returns `true` whereas I would expect it to return `false`.

So basically, why does the code below return true and 0 ?

```
String testThis = "";
String fileName = "blablablabla";
System.out.println(fileName.contains(testThis));
System.out.println(fileName.indexOf(testThis));
```

Logically (at least to me) `""` does not occur in `blablablabla` but `indexOf("")` says it does, why?

Comment: How would you prove there is not an empty string at the start of fileName? You would have to find a character that appears in the empty string but does not appear in fileName.

Comment: Ï think, at least thats why I'm here, a contains search on "" should throw exception because its illogical. I'm sure from some c basic 30 years ago attitude, this is complient with old compilers.. But its not logical for a _normal_ person.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

An empty string occurs in every string. Specifically, a contiguous subset of the string must match the empty string. Any empty subset is contiguous and any string has an empty string as such a subset.

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

An empty set of char values exists in any string, at the beginning, end, and between characters. Out of anything, you can extract nothing. From a physical piece of string/yarn I can say that a zero-length portion exists within it.

If contains returns true there is a possible `substring(` invocation to get the string to find. `"aaa".substring(1,1)` should return `""`, but don't quote me on that as I don't have an IDE at the moment.

Comment: @george_h More like uselessly formal at the beginning :D

Comment: If it needs an explanation its not logical. This is just one of those things that just are the way they are. If strings _always contains empty_ the search is pointless and developer should be made aware.

Comment: @Christian if strings did not contain empty substrings, then the definition of contains would be badly inconsistent with mathematical theory, which is arguably worse.

Answer (score 11):

`""` occurs between every character and also at start and end.